# SharePoint Online - Show column description or full column name when hovering the column header

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, column

We currently have a SharePoint list that has quite many columns, with describing column names making the column names take up quite a lot of width. Many of them get cut off in the middle of the name, since we're trying to save some space so the users doesn't have to scroll too much horizontally. See picture below:

[image]

If you change to grid view, you get a tooltip displaying the full column name when hovering the column headers. See picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve something similar in the "normal" list view? Either where you get a tooltip with the full column name or the column description. Similar to the grid-view.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no OOB ways to  have a tooltip displaying the full column name when hovering the column headers. I would suggest you submit a feedback in user voice here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration